# How to enable huge pages in Raspbian Stretch Lite?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

How can I enable huge pages in Raspbian Stretch?  I have followed instructions for Debian (https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages#Enabling_HugeTlbPage) without success (reboot puts my Pi 3 into 'emergency' mode, can't log back in, have to start with a fresh image).  I have also tried (from https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/issues/32):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=5
```

But this has no effect (since the file 'nr_hugepages' does not exist).

Is there something specific for Raspbian that I'm missing?

Comment: And you are shure that the kernel have been compiled with hugepages support?

Comment: I'm not fully sure. I've had no luck finding specific discussion of huge pages in the official Raspberry Pi forums (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/), but huge pages are supported in Debian (from which Raspbian is ported). I've submitted a post with the same question to the official Raspberry Pi forum: we'll see what they say.

Comment: My thread at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=206014 hasn't gained much traction:  It has supplied a few new references, which might be useful to someone with more experience, but nothing I'm able to distill into a procedure so far...

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information I can find online ([example here](https://github.com/lgeek/arm_tlb_huge_pages)), I don't believe the ARM Cortex-A7 used in the Raspberry Pi supports Huge Pages in the L1 TLB, so it most likely won't work properly due to the Hardware itself.

If someone finds a more definitive answer, please let us know!

Comment: Great reference! I hadn't seen that, and I can't pretend to understand it all (my linux-fu is not strong). The capabilities of the ARM are of importance here: the Cortex-A7 for the Pi 2 and the Cortex-A53 for the later Pi 2's and Pi 3's. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Huge pages are supported from Raspberry PI 4B. The supported huge page sizes are:

```
 - 1 GB
 - 32 MB
 - 2 MB (default)
 - 64 KB
```

As a side note, for more details, I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64914391/14393739) on StackOverflow which explains how to configure and use them. But it is for Raspberry Pi OS 64 bits (formerly called Raspbian).

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit the question. For a start, you cannot run Raspbian Strech on a Pi 4. You'd better ask a new question (and answer it) if you feel like sharing your findings. And don't just link to an SO question, explain how to enable huge pages on a Pi and what are the benefits of doing so.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: The answer at least says that Huge Pages are likely not supported on RPI3 which is part of the question no ?